# "preRenderComponent" is ignored when "viewParam" is present in parent view

Tags: jsf, metadata, composite-component

I need a method to be executed whenever my component gets rendered, i.e. when it gets created for the first time and on every update.

A way of doing it is using f:metadata and f:event for the event "preRenderComponent". It works perfectly well, unless I also have a f:metadata with f:viewParam in the view holding the component. If I have a f:viewParam in the parent view, f:event, in the component, gets ignored.

How to solve this problem, why does it happen?

Here's some code to reproduce the problem:

The view (index.xhtml):

```
<h:body>
  <f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="vparam" value="#{index.vparam}" />
  </f:metadata>

  <comp:component />
</h:body>
```

The managedBean (Index.java)

```
@ManagedBean(name="index")
public class Index implements Serializable {
    private String vparam;

    public void setVparam(String vparam) {
        this.vparam = vparam;
    }

    public String getVparam() {
        return vparam;
    }
}
```

The component view (component.xhtml):

```
<h:body>
    <composite:interface componentType="component" />
    <composite:implementation>
        <f:metadata>
            <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cc.generateString}" />
        </f:metadata>
        <h:outputText value="#{cc.string}" />
    </composite:implementation>
</h:body>
```

The component's java class (Component.java):

```
@FacesComponent(value="component")
public class Component extends UINamingContainer implements Serializable {
    private String string;

    public void generateString(){
        System.out.println("*** PRE RENDERING COMPONENT...");
        System.out.flush();
        string = "It worked!";
    }

    public String getString(){
        return string;
    }
}
```

The expected output of this code is: the string "It worked!" printed in the index page.
The actual output is: nothing, since a null string is printed as "" by the h:outputText.

In the log file, "***** PRE RENDERING COMPONENT..." is not printed, it's never executed.

If I remove the following line from index.xhtml, everything works fine:

```
<f:viewParam name="vparam" value="#{index.vparam}" />
```

Why does the presence of "viewParam" in the component's parent page makes JSF to ignore "f:event" in the component?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the `<f:metadata>` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html), the view can have **only one** `<f:metadata>` which needs to go in **template client** (the top level XHTML page which is been opened upon HTTP request).

The `<f:metadata>` in the composite is displaced. It doesn't belong there. Get rid of it. The `<f:event>` does by itself not  require to be placed inside `<f:metadata>`. This works as intented:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cc.generateString}" />
    ...
</composite:implementation>
```

Your concrete problem is caused because the second `<f:metadata>` is ignored altogether including all of its children.

True, you're seeing a lot of `<f:metadata><f:viewParam><f:event type="preRenderView">` examples, but the `<f:event>` is in this specific case actually a workaround and just for self-documentary purposes placed inside the very same `<f:metadata>` as the `<f:viewParam>`s it needs to work with. In JSF 2.2, the right way has been introduced in flavor of `<f:viewAction>`. See also [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Since I don't intend to upgrade to JSF 2.2 for now, I used the f:event outside f:metadata, it's working fine now ;)